# Call R script from H2O

Tags: r, pojo, h2o

I have a model built in R that runs via POJO on an H2O cluster. I need the values spat out by the model to be fed into an R script that does a bunch of calculations/scaling for our purposes.

1. Can this script be called directly from H2O?
2. Is my understanding correct in that *only* ML models created in H2O can be exported to a POJO? Or would it be possible to export this R script as a POJO as well?

Edit: Adding more details for clarity.

An existing POJO is used in our production instance of H2O, and is invoked via a service that returns the required data as a JSON object. The JSON object is then passed by the service to the R script, which does a bunch of calculations/scaling and then returns the results. Essentially, the R script is not part of the H2O ecosystem and I'm trying to make it so. Ideally I'd like to export the script as a POJO but I'm not sure if it's possible, given that the script isn't a model per se.

Answer (score 0):

What you are saying above is little hard to understand

- You can use R script with H2O to build a model.
- H2O generates 3 kinds of models - Binary, POJO and MOJO
- Once a model is build with H2O, using R or Python script you have opportunity to export models in either of all of above types
- The binary model needs exact same version of H2O running to do the scoring
- Other 2 models POJO and MOJO models needs Java run time to score, however you don't need to H2O with POJO and MOJO.
- POJO and MOJO scoring is explained [here](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-docs/src/product/howto/POJO_QuickStart.md) and [here](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-docs/src/product/howto/MOJO_QuickStart.md) respectively.

Based on above your first sentence is not clear and first point needs more clarity what you really doing and what do you want. Looks like you are mixing multiple independent things together which is hard to understand.

About your second point, yes H2O can export models as POJO or MOJO. If you have a R script which can run with H2O to generate model then you sure can use R script to generate POJO from H2O.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to score on new data in batch from inside R, it would be easier to save your model with h2o.saveModel() and load it back with h2o.loadModel().

And then make predictions with h2o.predict().